# AJAX/JS not displaying alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm learning AJAX/JS and once the form has been submitted, I want AJAX to fire off the POST and return the data. This has been done and the data comes back OK and sucessfully, I just cannot get the 'alert' function to show. I get redirected to my process.php with the following:

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"email":"Email is required.","password":"Password is required."}}
```

I now need to get the above to display in an 'alert', such as alert('Password is required');

This is my 'process.js' form:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
event.preventDefault();
$('form').submit(function(event) 
{
    var formData = {
        'email'         : $('input[email=email').val(),
        'password'      : $('input[password=password').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'ajax/proclogin.php',
        data        : JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType    : 'json',
            encode  : true 
    })

        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);

            if (!data.success)
            {
                if(data.errors.email)
                {
                    //toastr.error(''+data.errors.email+'', 'Oops!');
                    alert('Email error');
                }
                if(data.errors.password)
                {
                    //toastr.error(''+data.errors.password+'', 'Oops!');
                    alert('Password Error');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //toastr.success('Works!', 'WooHoo!');
                alert('Works.');
            }
        });
});
});
```

This is the 'proclogin.php' file:

```
<?php
// proc(ess)login.php

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

// validate the variables 
======================================================
// if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

if (empty($_POST['password']))
    $errors['password'] = 'Password is required.';

// return a response ===========================================================

// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if ( ! empty($errors)) {

    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {

    // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message
        $connection = mysqli_connect("*****","****","****","*****");
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']); # Define email field
        $input = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']); # Define password field

        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `Email`, `Password` FROM users WHERE Email='$email' LIMIT 1"); # Query what we need
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); # Fetch what we need

        $p = $row['Password']; # Define fetched details
        $email = $row['Email']; # Define fetched details
        if(password_verify($input, $p)) # Verify input password matches hashed password in the DB.
        {
            #It matches, let's set a session and redirect them to the dashboard.php page.
            $_SESSION['SID'] = $email;
            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['message'] = 'Success';
        }
        else
        {
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['message'] = 'fail';

       }


    // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
}

// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

Comment: That code should throw an error. You need to move `event.preventDefault();` inside the `submit` handler.

Comment: Done that but it still redirects the page and doesn't show the 'alert'.

Comment: If it redirects it means there's still an error in your JS. Did you check the browser's console?

Comment: I see an error now... But I don't see how it's unexpected. I get "Unexpected token } on line 40" being the last line in the process.js. I have all correct }); or } in the file :(

Answer (score 0):

You have `event.preventDefault();` outside of your submit handler, it should be inside.
The selector you use to get the password and email seems wrong.
You're attempting to send JSON but trying to read form data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();// prevent the form from submitting normally
    var formData = {
        'email'         : $('input[type=email').val(),  // get the value of the email input
        'password'      : $('input[type=password').val() // get the value of the password input
    };

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'ajax/proclogin.php',
        data        : formData,  // send as form data 
        dataType    : 'json',
    })
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if isset the email or password then show the alert message like this:

```
.done(function(data) {
        if(data.errors.email) {
            alert('email required');
        }
        else if(data.errors.password) {
            alert('password required');
        }
        else {
            alert('done');
        }
    })
.fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
```

and remove the condition  `if (!data.success)`

Comment: remove the condition `if (!data.success)` from `.done`

Comment: replace `if(data.success == false)`  by `if(!data.success)`

Comment: That still hasn't worked. I still get redirected and the alert doesn't show.

Comment: remove `$('form').submit(function(event)`  and handle it through `.click()` eg `$('.btn-submit').click(function()`

Comment: .submit reload your page thats why it does not show alert dialog you need to do it by .click event

Comment: Still nothing. $('#login_button').click(function() and without the hash tag. Also with .btn-submit.

Comment: check the console in developer mode what kind of error it gives you

Comment: I did check that in Chrome and the console doesn't print out any error messages.